# Git pull/Git clone returns blank value when using Invoke-Expression powershell

Tags: git, powershell, git-clone, git-pull

I am trying to run a *Git pull* and *Git Clone* command using `Invoke-Expression` mentioned below. In case there are any failures when running the below command, I wanted to capture the details on a variable so I can output the code accordingly. but unfortunately when using the below commands, it returns a blank variable with no output.

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "git pull https://$($UserName):$($Password)@$Gitpath --rebase" -OutVariable Gitresult 2>&1

Invoke-Expression -Command "git clone https://$($UserName):$($Password)@$Gitpath" -OutVariable Gitresult 2>&1
```

Kindly suggest, how I can get the output irrespective of success or failure events.

If there are any alternatives, please share.

Answer (score 0):

`git` is kind of a weird cli as it makes use of stderr quite a bit.  You don't need `Invoke-Expression` at all here:

```
$url = "https://${UserName}:${Password}@${Gitpath}"

$gitPullResult = git pull $url --rebase 2>&1
$gitCloneResult = git clone $url 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Seems like using the above version also if the git pull or clone fails, still the variable does have blank output unfortunately.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue.  I tested from PowerShell 5.1 and it works as expected.